# ServiceStack route for GET and List Collection

Tags: routes, servicestack

I wanted to know if I could call this with a route? I can call this code from my internal services without issues.  I don't see how I can send a collection to the route without adding a property to hold the collection. To rephrase, can I call a Route\API and send a collection?

```
public void Post(List<InsertNotificationLogs> request)
{
    var notifications = request.ConvertTo<List<NotificationLogs>>();
    notifications.ForEach(x => x.AuditUserId = UserAuth.Id);
    Db.InsertAll(notifications);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Request DTOs in ServiceStack must be a single non-generic Request DTO concrete Type.

From [Auto Batched Request Docs](https://docs.servicestack.net/auto-batched-requests#defining-a-request-dto-to-accept-a-collection-of-types), to define a Request DTO that accepts a collection of DTOs you can inherit from a generic `List<T>`, e.g:

```
public class InsertNotificationLogs : List<InsertNotificationLog> {}

public void Post(InsertNotificationLogs request)
{
    var notifications = request.ConvertTo<List<NotificationLogs>>();
    notifications.ForEach(x => x.AuditUserId = UserAuth.Id);
    Db.InsertAll(notifications);
}
```